# Copy text to lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I would like to setup a workflow to update a column to a lookup column.

1. Document library
2. Vendor custom list

Document library contains calculated column for equipment number, and a lookup column to the vendor custom list.

I need to copy the content of the `Equipment Number` field to the `Equip` lookup field.

Is this possible? When I do a copy/paste when in dataview it works fine.

thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Did your VendorEquipment list have all unique Equipment Number values?

Answer (score 2):

try following steps

1. Create workflow on new/edit
2. Add step : Set field in current item
3. Replace following tokens -  Field : Equip
4. Value :

   Data source : VendorEquipment (list),

   field from data source : Equipment number,

   **find list item**

   field: Equipment number

   value : Current item : Equipment number

This should resolve your issue

Comment: thanks Monica, but still doesnt seem to work, i did read somewhere else about having to link up the lookup field ID rather than the name, and when i link the ID i get exception errors in the workflow... i am really baffled here and i am thinking it shouldnt be this hard to update a lookup field... especially when i can copy / paste no problem when in datasheet view.

Comment: hello Monica i linked the field from source: ID instead and now its working.. thanks abunch