# Update Lookup Field value, from Text field value in the same list using workflow

Tags: sharepoint-server, lookup-column

i have come across a scenario where i should update lookup field value from single line text field in the same list (lookup field used for splitting text/string).

Is this possible to update the lookup field using workflow in the same list..

i have tried using spd 2010 workflow,

ListA has 2 fields, Destinations (Single line text) and Destinations1 (lookup field mapped to ID of same list),

Here i need to update Destinations1 with user input values from Destinations using workflow.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are not able to use workflow to update the Lookup type of column value with the text column value.

**Update**:

Since the value of Lookup column formats as ID + ;# + lookup text value, if we don't change the type of lookup, we cannot change the value based on a text column.

Besides, since the lookup column get information from another column, if the text value is not including in this column, it will not get the information.

The workaround I can give is change the lookup column type.

**Update:**

We can create a workflow as below to update lookup column based on a text column:

[image]

My List1 is the list which lookup column get information from, Title is the column which lookup column get information from, field2 is the Single line text column.

Comment: if not, can i have alternative solution. Maybe using 2 lists

Comment: Hi Sudhir, I update my reply, check it.

Comment: Hi Hellofiona, Can i use two lists A and B and update lookup field (since i need this for splitting the text ;Delimited Text).

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/165456/copy-text-to-lookup-column please check this link, there are similar queries and have been solved but are not clear. Can you help to solve

Comment: Hi Sudhir, based on the link you provide, I update my reply, check if it helps.

Comment: that was simple and work done well, thank you

Comment: If it helps, you can mark it as answer. Thanks for understanding.